# MySQL Query in CodeIgniter with Session ID

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysql

Let's say I have a query:

```
" SELECT * FROM table 
      WHERE donor_id = " .$this->session->userdata('id') ." 
      GROUP BY rating"
```

However, it appears that I get a mysql syntax error here, citing that `$this->session->userdata('id')` gives me '25' for example, instead of 25.  Are there any workarounds here to prevent `$this->session->userdata('id')` from being quoted?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intval($this->session->userdata('id'))`

Answer (score 2):

In CI, I do this all the time:

```
$id = intval($this->session->userdata('id'));
$sql = "  SELECT * ".
       "    FROM table ".
       "   WHERE donor_id = {$id} ". 
       "GROUP BY rating ";
//process $sql below
```

Creating query like this will make you easier to spot bug and prevent SQL injection. Use concatenation when you need to split query to multiple lines instead of make it a long multiple string is to prevent the actual query string got too long. Indent the SQL keyword is to make it easier spot logical and syntax bug.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean that it is returning you a string instead of an integer you could always try using `settype` or `intval`:

```
$var = '2';
settype($var, "integer");
$var = intval($var);
```

However, if you mean that the quotes are for some reason hard-coded in, you could do a string replace, if you are sure that the value will not contain quotes:

```
ech str_replace("'", "", "'2'"); // prints 2
```